# Django HyperlinkedModelSerializer on a table that has a field marked as pk + fk

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have this table which has a field marked as a primary key, when it also is a foreign key. Isn't ideal, but need to deal with this at the moment.

```html
class Profile(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Profiles"
        
    member = models.OneToOneField(
        Member,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )

    ...
```

Now I have a django-rest-framework serializer for the Member and Profile models, that looks like this,

```html
class MemberSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
       model = Member
       fields = ('id', 'role_id', 'user_id')
       
class MemberProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
       model = Profile
       fields = ['member_id','bio','address','mobile']
```

The question I have is that, when I have the 'member_id' extracted from MemberProfileSerializer, it lists down the id correctly (this is the id that is pk for Profile, and is also fk to the Member table)

But if I need to extract more information from the Member model, and to do that, if I add a reference to the MemberSerializer, I get back an empty object in the results!

```html
class MemberProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    member_id = MemberSerializer()
    class Meta:
       model = Profile
       fields = ['member_id','bio','address','mobile']
```

[image]

Further, if I add an HyperlinkedRelatedField entry for member_id,

```html
class MemberProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

        member_id = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
            view_name = 'member-detail',
            lookup_field='id',
            read_only=True)
            
        class Meta:
           model = Profile
           fields = ['member_id','bio','address','mobile']
```

I get the following error.

"'int' object has no attribute 'id'"

Basically, somehow the serializer is not seeing this field as a foreign key at all. Any way to force the behavior?

Comment: Why not use model inheritance where `Profile` inherits from `Member`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/

Comment: I already have a inheritance defined, @WillemVanOnsem. 

My Profile model has a "member = models.OneToOneField(..." defined.

Comment: yes, but that is exactly what Django does for model inheritance. The advantage however is that you can thus work with such model, and it will include the "parent" fields. In other words, by using model inheritance, a lot of tasks are simplified. For example querying will automatically be done with a JOIN on the profile table.

Comment: That's interesting! Will explore this further.. 
I'm still however not able to map how the inheritance will help me here.. My serializer is 'locked' to the Profile model. I get a "user_id does not exist in Profile" error if I just attempt  to look for member fields, in profile.

Answer (score 0):

Actually. Foolish me.
Had to reference the member object in profile, as 'member' and not 'member_id'.

```html
class MemberProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

        member = MemberSerializer()
            
        class Meta:
           model = Profile
           fields = ['member','bio','address','mobile']
```

Willem, Thanks for your suggestions!